# Click and drop data from one textbox to another textbox

Tags: javascript

I want to create a functionality where when I click the data in Textbox1 (the data is basically a button with "tick" as shown in the image link below), then the data should be transferred to TextBox2 and should no longer appear in TextBox1.
Also from Textbox2 if I click the data (button with "X" image), then again the data should be transferred from TextBox2 to Textbox1 and Textbox2 should no longer contain the data.
I am working on dojo. But it would be fine if the answers are not related to dojo.
I wanted to know if there are any features available in dojo for this.
A javascript hint would also be helpful :)

[image: Click and drop functionality]

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: please do not post just images to clarify your problem. We need to see the code for effective help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code requires to showing your efforts

Comment: Please review an answer santosh, I update an answer which exactly meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("mouseover", ".opt", function(e) {
  $(this).attr({color: "#0000ff"});
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".opt", function(e) {
    var _divOpt;
    var _parent = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    var _index = $(this).index();
    var _html = $('<a/>')
      .attr({
        "class": "opt",
        "href": "javascript:void(0)"
      })
      .append($(this).clone())      
      .html();
    if ("div1" === _parent) {
      $(".div2").append(_html);
    } else {
      $(".div1").append(_html);
    }

    $(this).remove();
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF0000;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.option-close{
  margin-left:50px;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

a div{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
a {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
  float: left;
  width:70%;  
}
a:hover, div:hover, div:hover{
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    <a class="opt" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div class="option_value">Option 1</div>
    </a>
    <a class="opt" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div class="option_value">Option 2</div>
    </a>
    <a class="opt" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div class="option_value">Option 3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```